# Setting abstract observation and action spaces with Gym library

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am new to RL (so sorry if my question turns out to be bad formulated or inconvinient) and want to build a tool that will make certain decisions in order to navigate through a web page to which I own the code. My goal is the agent to take different actions based on the page content, for which I am using Selenium driver. I have already done a similar thing with random actions, but I would like to know how I can do it with reinforcement Learning. Nevertheless, I am facing a few challenges (using Gym library).

On the one hand, I am currently working with an image if the current page status as my observation. Nevertheless, I'd like to test different representations (graphs, feature extraction array, etc.), but I do not understand how to define those observations spaces. For example, currently I am using this representation for the image:

```
required_width = self.driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
required_height = self.driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(required_height, required_width,4) , dtype=np.uint8)
```

But I am having quite a few problems with dynamic length images and/or using other data types like graphs and lists.

On the other hand, a similar thing happens for me in terms of actions. I have a function that checks the current page status and looks for possible actions (clicks, file uploads, etc.). The thing is that the way in which I store my actions in the moment is using a dynamic dictionary that has differently shaped elements (and a changing size depending on the current state). These actions are defined as tuples of action-type (the dictionary key) and element information (tag, class, id, style etc.). This element information may include some other keys, for example, if the input is a text input, the action will be defined by the action type, the input and the content to insert). For instance, a valid action set could be:

```
{'click': 
    [
        {'element': <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3a999c75e7cd38e40a3c4ffcf2c4b16f", element="7a7a8e6f-6de1-4848-9936-71844ae1c779")>, 
        'tag': 'button', 
        'id': '', 
        'name': '', 
        'class': 'button button--icon open-nav-button', 
        'type': 'submit', 
        'inner_text': '', 
        'outer_html': '<button class="button button--icon open-nav-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-menu icon icon--m"><line x1="3" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line><line x1="3" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line><line x1="3" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line></svg></button>'
        }
    ], 
'write': 
    [
        {'input': 
            {'element': <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3a999c75e7cd38e40a3c4ffcf2c4b16f", element="b46dbe8a-6231-4ccd-9fd3-43089eada994")>, 
            'tag': 'input', 
            'id': 'title', 
            'name': 'title', 
            'class': 'field', 
            'type': 'text', 
            'inner_text': '', 
            'outer_html': '<input type="text" name="title" class="field" required="required" placeholder="abc" id="title" aria-label="abc" maxlength="250">'
            }, 
            'content': '\asdnaksjdhaksfahf isdjadjfh aj'}
        ], 
'select': 
    [
        {
            'select_element': 
                {
                    'element': <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a49ef8736acad9ea092bd651e662c7f9", element="c9750d85-9c35-4c7e-98dd-d4b8b2e84124")>, 
                    'tag': 'select', 
                    'id': 'language-select', 
                    'name': '', 
                    'class': 'language-dropdown', 
                    'type': 'select-one', 
                    'inner_text': 'Castellano\English', 
                    'outer_html': '<select id="language-select" class="language-dropdown">\n\n<option id="es" value="/app/language/es_ES" selected="selected">Castellano</option><option id="eu" value="/app/language/en_EN">English</option>\n\n<script>\n$(\'#language-select\').change(function(){\n\t$(\'.spinner-layout\').show();\n\tlocation = this.value;\n});\n</script>\n\n</select>'
                }, 
            'option_element': 
                {
                    'element': <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a49ef8736acad9ea092bd651e662c7f9", element="e027bd8d-b8a6-45f6-af85-9090d5cc68bb")>,
                    'tag': 'option', 
                    'id': 'es',
                    'name': None,
                    'class': '',
                    'type': None,
                    'inner_text': 'Castellano',
                    'outer_html': '<option id="es" value="/app/language/es_ES" selected="selected">Castellano</option>'
                }
        }
    ],
'upload': []
}
```

Comment: Check out miniwob++: https://miniwob.farama.org/index.html